# How to enable inline quick edit in Blogger?

Tags: html, blogger

In Blogger, I need to edit a page all the time, because of frequent updates. Each time I want to edit the content, I am redirected to the editing page, like what happens on a Stack Exchange site for a new user trying to edit content.

Is it possible to add a real time `quick--inline` (Ajax?)`--editing` customization to Blogger, like the one a [Stack Exchange user gets at 2,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (See the attached picture)? This will help me in reducing lot of unwanted wastage of time.

Edit: I searched for inline WYSIWYG editors, and found TinyMce; but don't have proper idea on going through the process of integrating it. The process of integrating it is going through complex steps, if anyone has any quick steps for integrating it, it will be helpful.

Picture Link:
[Quick Edit in Stack Exchange at 2,000 or more reputation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQmcZ.png)
[image]

Edit (2/2/17): I am now trying Open Live Writer, which doesn't give inline editing ability inside the site itself, but instead in its own field interface with the looks of the original blog. This doesn't help in seeing the blog being updated live in the web, but it will be updated even if not seen. To see it we need to make an extra step of looking it in the web, this is still a step which could be eliminated. This is better than before, but I am still looking for inline editing within the blogger site as like StackExhcange does.

Comment: This is decided by blogger's and stackodrflows server side code and logic. Maybe blogger uses old time post, and stackoverflow ajax. Basically its development team's decision, not us users

Comment: I have posted on this in Blogger Help Forum, here is the link to it: [Inline Editing](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/nzGbwr92zjY;context-place=forum/blogger).

Comment: Yes, thats right, but keep in mind that we, as a users's can not add code to SO or Blogger. Yes, we can add content, & some basic scripting, but thats all. Only the developers of these companies can add code to their servers, especially ajax.

Comment: There are many plugins for WordPress for adding this feature of inline.editing, doesn't that sign on the possibility of we adding code for having this customization?

Comment: No, wordpress hosted version is the one where you are not user, but owner of code, can edit n change. Users in that case are the people who read your blog. You make changes, decide ajax or not, readers just have to go with it. Readers can't add ajax on WordPress managed by you. You might change or add ajax to blogger only if you are Google. Google gave us a CMS, where we as users can add update pages. Limited only.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have been not clear in mentioning me to be the owner of blog! I have the privilege of editing code, but I don't know the plugin code here, can you help me now? Thank you for the time.

Comment: You're asking how to create an embedded WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: @TylerH: Thank you for the comment. Now, if I want to edit a post in the blogger, it takes me to a different page, where I need to edit and then save back. Is it possible to edit the content of the post without redirection, like inline-editing or a popup editor on the same page? This is what I want. Sorry, I gave a lengthy answer. Yes, it will....

Comment: ....be helpful if an WYSIWYG editor embedded on the same page is opened up, if the owner of the post clicks on the edit button.

Comment: It seems like it should be possible to create a custom Blogger widget that could implement an inline WYSIWYG editor. That being said, as your question stands now it is too broad and off-topic for this site.

Comment: You can add a pencil in settings

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer Something like this would only be possible by using Blogger API (https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/getting_started). Most likely you will have to create a browser extension to implement a functionality like this.

Comment: @DaniSpringer: Thank you for the comment. Are you saying about pencil icon for edit option? Yes, I do have it now. But, when I click on it, it takes me to a new page, where I need to edit the post/page, and then save it back. What I want now is the editing ability without going to another page, as like the one given in the above picture link.

Comment: @PrayagVerma: Are there any such already existing browser extensions?

Comment: Maybe a feature request is the way to go here. I'd certainly appreciate the ability to edit blogposts inline.

Answer (score 1):

As the creator of the question said on the comments, he asked the question on Google Product Forums and the formal response was:

1. There's no such a native feature available for inline editing.
2. There's no Blogger plugin supported that could resolve the issue.

The full response can be found here: 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/nzGbwr92zjY;context-place=forum/blogger